# Efficient generalized suffix array/tree construction for prefix trees

Tags: suffix-trees, suffix-array, trie

Is there any algorithm that can efficiently construct a [generalized suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) or array (or something similar) for a set of strings represented by a prefix tree (trie)?

In particular, I'm wondering:

- How time-efficient an algorithm for this can be
- How space-efficient the resulting data structure can be
- What algorithm(s) might be able to do this, if any